# Perl web scraper, retrieve data from text inside a script tag

Tags: html, perl, web-scraping, web-crawler

So far I was using perl to obtain data from web pages using `HTML::TreeBuilder`. This was OK when the data was contained inside `meta` or `div` tags; but now I stumbled upon a new structure that I don't know how to crawl, though it looks pretty trivial.

```html
<html lang="en">
    <body>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            panel.web.bootstrapData = {
                "data": {
                    "units": "kW",
                    "horsePower": 100.00
                }
            };
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

The example displays the relevant part of the content that I get from the web. I would like to get the values for `units` and `horsePower`.

Fragments of the code I was using so far:

```perl
use strict;
use LWP::UserAgent;
use HTTP::Request::Common;
use HTML::TreeBuilder;

[...]

$reply = $ua->get($url, @ns_headers);

# printing the reply would get us the first code snippet.
print $reply->content;

unless ($reply->is_success) {
    [...]
}

my $tree = HTML::TreeBuilder->new_from_content($reply->content);
my @unit_array = $tree -> look_down(_tag=>'meta','itemprop'=>'unit');
my $unit = $unit_array[0]->attr('content');

[...]
```

Any one knows how to obtain the relevant data and whether I should use something other than `HTML::TreeBuilder` for that matter? I haven't found any similar cases searching through stackoverflow and the web.

Comment: That's a very different problem. What you intend to do is parse/scrape JavaScript code, not HTML. The contents of the `script` tag are a JS program you will have to parse with a radically different approach, I'm afraid.

Comment: @JesusAlonsoAbad I agree that is true for the general case. But OPs example clearly indicates that his source data has JSON strings embedded in the `<script>` tags.

Comment: Thanks for your comments. Stefan's solution works perfectly fine in my case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are basically on the right path. But [HTML::TreeBuilder](https://metacpan.org/pod/HTML::TreeBuilder) doesn't understand anything about JavaScript.

The approach:

- find the `<script>` nodes
- extract the JSON content from those nodes

  - **NOTE:** this will be easy for the example given, but will require more finesse for more complicated `<script>` content
  - The escape `\;` in the regex isn't really required, but the SO syntax highlighter gets confused without it
- use [JSON](https://metacpan.org/pod/JSON) to decode the string to Perl data structures
- access those data structures in your script

A first rough solution without error checking. I left some debugging lines, commented out, in the code so that you can trace what each step is doing:

```perl
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;

use Data::Dumper;
use HTML::TreeBuilder;
use JSON;

my $decoder = new JSON;

my $tree       = HTML::TreeBuilder->new_from_file(\*DATA);
#$tree->dump;
my @scripts    = $tree->look_down(_tag => 'script');
#$scripts[0]->dump;
# NOTE 1: ->as_text() *DOES NOT* return <script> content!
# NOTE 2: ->as_HTML() probably doesn't work for all cases, i.e. escaping
my $javascript = ($scripts[0]->content_list())[0];
#print "${javascript}\n";
my($json)      = $javascript =~ /(\{.+\})\;/s;
#print "${json}\n";
my $object     = $decoder->decode($json);

print Dumper($object);
print "FOUND: units: ", $object->{data}->{units},
      " horsepower: ",  $object->{data}->{horsePower}, "\n";

# IMPORTANT: $tree needs to be destroyed by hand when you're done with it!
$tree->delete;

exit 0;

__DATA__
<html lang="en">
    <body>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            panel.web.bootstrapData = {
                "data": {
                    "units": "kW",
                    "horsePower": 100.00
                }
            };
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Test run:

```
$ perl dummy.pl
$VAR1 = {
          'data' => {
                      'horsePower' => '100',
                      'units' => 'kW'
                    }
        };
FOUND: units: kW horsepower: 100
```

Comment: Just tried your solution and it works perfectly. Just had to adjust the regex because the actual web had a couple more JSONs under the `<script>` tag. Thanks.

Comment: I think `->as_HTML()` may not be the best choice, although it works for your example. I've updated my answer to use `->content_list()` instead.